# Removes duplicate values from an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have an array generated with  CodeIgniter using MySQL. The values in   `[co_name] =>`  are duplicated and I tried to `group_by` it using `co_id` and its not working ,but it also `group_by` using `order_id`.CodeIgniter `group_by` is working for only one `group_by` or any other method to **removes duplicate values** form the `[co_name] =>`.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [order_date] => 1408255199
            [cus_id] => 6
            [order_deliver_name] => Jankia
            [order_deliver_add_no] => 5085
            [order_deliver_add_street] => mapanawathura road
            [order_deliver_add_city] => Kandy
            [order_deliver_contact] => 0716352632
            [order_deliver_date] => 2014-08-12
            [order_status] => pending
            [emp_id] => 
            [cmp_name] => Burger Bun 
            [co_name] => Put Ham 
Put Tomato 
Put Ham 
Put Tomato 
Put Chilli Sauce 
Put Tomato 
Put Chilli Sauce 
Put Ham 
Put Chilli Sauce 
            [order_id] => 28
            [quantity] => 10
        )
```

Here is my code

```
function get_customize_orders(){

        $this->db->select(array(

            'tbl_order_product_details.order_date',
            'tbl_order_product_details.cus_id',
            'tbl_order_product_details.order_deliver_name',
            'tbl_order_product_details.order_deliver_add_no',
            'tbl_order_product_details.order_deliver_add_street',
            'tbl_order_product_details.order_deliver_add_city',
            'tbl_order_product_details.order_deliver_contact',
            'tbl_order_product_details.order_deliver_date',
            'tbl_order_product_details.order_status',
            'tbl_order_product_details.emp_id',
            'tbl_customise_main_product.cmp_name',
            'GROUP_CONCAT(tbl_customise_optional.co_name SEPARATOR "<br />" ) as co_name ',
            'tbl_order_products.order_id',
            'tbl_order_products.quantity',
        ));
        $this->db->from('tbl_order_products');
        $this->db->join('tbl_customise_join_products', 'tbl_customise_join_products.cmp_id=tbl_order_products.product_id');
        $this->db->join('tbl_customise_main_product', 'tbl_customise_main_product.cmp_id=tbl_customise_join_products.cmp_id');
        $this->db->join('tbl_customise_order_products', 'tbl_customise_order_products.order_id=tbl_order_products.order_id');
        $this->db->join('tbl_customise_optional', 'tbl_customise_optional.co_id=tbl_customise_order_products.co_id');
        $this->db->join('tbl_order_product_details', 'tbl_order_product_details.order_id=tbl_order_products.order_id');
        $this->db->group_by('tbl_order_products.order_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` in `GROUP_CONCAT` so it will concatenate only distinct `co_name` per `order_id` group

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tbl_customise_optional.co_name SEPARATOR "<br />" ) as co_name
```